# Android SDK and Intel HAXM

Tags: android, emulation, intel, haxm

I am running Windows 8.1 on a fairly decent piece of hardware. The CPU is a Intel Xeon E5-1620-v2 @ 3.7 GHz accessing 16 GB of RAM. So my processor definitly supports VT-x which is needed according to this article [Speeding Up the Android* Emulator on Intel® Architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture).

However the installation package complains with:

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

I am running Hyper-V on this machine, so I am pretty sure VT-x is enabled. Any input on this?

Comment: Just try Genymotion. My feeling it is faster than Intel acceleration

Comment: It seems Hyper-V and HAXM are mutually exlusive... will give genymotion a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Microsoft's Hypervisor is disabled/uninstalled from system features.

When enabled Windows will boot into a light virtual session. This prevents another hypervisor from using the hardware because the system is already virtualized.

*Edit:* If you don't want to completely nuke Hyper-V, Scott Hanselman has a [solution](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx), where you can edit your boot menu to enable/disable Hyper-V.

Comment: sweeet!!! Thanks a lot! The boot menu solution sounds promising, as I cant/wont completely nuke Hyper-V